# I grow, but I'm not alive

Tags: riddle

> Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.
>
> A force of nature holds me together.
>
> I grow, but I'm not alive.

**What am I?**

**Edit**: Fuzzy is in reference to appearance and force is in reference to fundamental forces (i.e. gravity, electromagnetism etc.)

Comment: I made some clarifications on the description because it seemed I was not descriptive enough based on some of the answers I was receiving.

Comment: Although Midori submitted the correct answer first, recognition to SaiBot for producing an equally acceptable answer prior to my description clarifications.

Comment: It doesn't match all the clues, but I was so tempted to answer DEBT!

Comment: You are: Cáncer

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since the puzzle has been updated and clarified a bit, I think you are a:

> Dust Bunny

*Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me*

> They are Fuzzy alright, but also made up of (among other things) dust, dead skin and even parasites, GROSS!

*A force of nature holds me together*

> they are held together by **STATIC ELECTRICITY**

*I grow, but I'm not alive*

> The more they stay on the ground, the bigger they get

Comment: +1 Yep you got it! All the descriptions are correct.

Comment: very nice riddle!

Answer (score 15):

Are you a

> black hole

Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me

> [Fuzzballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory)) are theorized by some superstring theory scientists to be the true quantum description of black holes. Regarding petting, well... this will be no fun.

A force of nature holds me together.

> Gravity

I grow, but I'm not alive.

> The more matter and energy they consume the bigger they get

Comment: Welcome to the puzzling community. Great answer, and well explained.

Comment: This answer is really good, but not the one I'm looking for. I had never heard of a 'fuzzball' in association with black holes so this answer seems to fit perfectly. I blame my description for being a tiny too broad.  If the correct answer isn't submitted with descriptions I'll accept this one.

Comment: I believe there shouldn't be a single correct answer. I would vote for this one being the better answer over the _standard_, intended answer!

Comment: @Colton Yeah, the clarification you added was good. Saying that "fuzzy" refers to appearance rules this out, and many of the other "wrong" ones.

Comment: Wow thanks for the feedback guys. This community is great!

Comment: @Colton - I really like your response to this answer. Typically the asker will say that an answer is wrong just because it isn't the intended answer.

Comment: Well, according to the no-hair theorem black holes aren't fuzzy at all... ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem

Answer (score 9):

Are you a

> Tumbleweed?

Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.

> They are fuzzy-ish but they might be pointy.

A force of nature holds me together.

> They are a tumble of weeds.

I grow, but I'm not alive.

> They die when they are unearthed from the ground and tumble around.

Comment: This answer almost makes me think I wasn't specific enough in description. The 'force of nature' I'm referring to is less to do with actual nature (trees, plants etc.) and more to do with forces (i.e. gravity, electromagnetism etc.). Additionally, the fact that a tumbleweed grows as a plant seems to eliminate from 'not being alive'. +1 for attempt though.

Answer (score 7):

are you

> the sun?

because

> Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.
>  *I wouldn't pet the sun, don't want to die*  
>  A force of nature holds me together.
>  *gravitation holds every Hydrogen molecule together* 
>  I grow, but I'm not alive.
> *the sun is expanding*

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that the sun was expanding o.0   +1

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie yep, it will "eat" Earth in billions years ;)

Comment: +1 for creativity and all the descriptions seem to match well accept fuzzy, wouldn't really call the sun fuzzy.

Comment: @Colton it sure looks fuzzy from "close up" with all the swirling fire stuff... Was about the write the same but was beaten by a minute. :D

Answer (score 6):

Are you:

> Memories

Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.

> Memories could be fuzzy and there is no way to pet them.

A force of nature holds me together.

> Nature definitely takes part in keeping your memories in place

I grow, but I'm not alive.

> The memories grow all the time as we grow older but they are not alive.

Answer (score 2):

are you by any chance (and this is looong shot) a:

> (Tornado) **Storm** ?

*Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me*

> Clouds look fuzzy, but you might get shocked!

*A force of nature holds me together*

> referencing the wind (and perhaps a tornado in the case of a Tornado storm, as kindly suggested by user QuantumTwinkie)

*I grow, but I'm not alive*

> Multiple clouds form a storm, the more they are, the bigger it gets

Comment: I wish I could pet that.

Comment: @PatJ i bet it feels like a mareep!

Comment: +1 for creativity, incorrect unfortunately. I've mad some edits to my description that could clear up some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

> You could be a [Dust Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_bunny) or maybe a [Dust Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_devil). I think the description might be too broad.

Comment: One of your answers is correct, I think you are right about description. I made a couple amendments. If you submit correct answer with descriptions I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you:

> Frost

Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.

> Frost is fuzzy.

A force of nature holds me together.

> Yep.  That fractally stuff that makes the pretty patterns.

I grow, but I'm not alive.

> Frost grows, but is not alive.

Comment: Welcome to the puzzling.SE community, hope you enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you :

> Mold?

Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.

> Mold is fuzzy but you don't want to touch it.

A force of nature holds me together.

> Decay is natural?

I grow, but I'm not alive.

> Mold grows and spreads but isn't alive

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you hide your answer inside spoiler tags, to avoid spoiling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves? Thanks!

Comment: sorry was trying to figure it out, thank you :D

Comment: Mold is a form of fungus - it is as alive as any plant!

Answer (score 1):

you might be:

> a nightmare

Although fuzzy, you don't want to pet me.

> Nightmares could be fuzzy and petting them could lead to insomnia.

A force of nature holds me together.

> Researchers were able to conclude that nightmares directly correlate with the stress in children's lives. - [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightmare)

I grow, but I'm not alive.

> The longer a nightmare lasts, the bigger it gets.